# MATLAB: Error in array2table

Tags: matlab

I'm not able resolve this error i face when running MATLAB's array2table function

> The VariableNames property must be a cell array, with each element
>   containing one nonempty character vector.

```
array2table([1,2,3],'VariableNames',{"str1", "str2", "str3"})
```

I had a read at MATLAB's [array2table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) documentation and my syntax mimick's MATLAB's give examples, hence i can't figure out where i went wrong. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrasing the error message: String and character arrays are different things. You're using cells of strings but the function expects you to use cells of characters. i.e.

```
array2table([1,2,3],'VariableNames',{'str1', 'str2', 'str3'})
```

---

<sup>Relevant documentation for further understanding: [*Characters and Strings*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)</sup>